# Is it possible to add a drop shadow to chart.js line chart?

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I'm using `chart.js` to build a line chart. I was wondering if it is possible to add a drop shadow to the line chart I'm displaying. To clarify I mean add a drop shadow to the line itself. Like this:

[image: https://dribbble.com/shots/1444038-Graph/attachments/213078]

Here is the code and code snippets.

```js
// Line Chart
var ctx = document.getElementById("salesData").getContext("2d");

var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,700,0);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(255, 204, 128, 1)');   
    gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(255, 152, 0, 1)');
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(239, 108, 0, 1)');

var salesData = {
  labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Front",
      fillColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
      strokeColor: gradient,
      pointColor: gradient,
      pointStrokeColor: "#202b33",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(225,225,225,0.9)",
      data: [0, 10, 40, 48, 55, 64, 55, 72]
    }
  ]
};


window.myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(salesData, {
  pointDotRadius : 0,
  pointDotStrokeWidth : 0,
  datasetStrokeWidth : 4,
  scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
  scaleGridLineWidth : 2,
  scaleShowGridLines : true,
  scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(225, 255, 255, 0.02)",
  scaleOverride: true,
  scaleSteps: 12,
  scaleStepWidth: 10,
  scaleStartValue: 0,

  responsive: true

});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="salesData"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extending the chart and overriding the `draw` function would be one (complicated) way to do this.

An easier way would be to duplicate the chart canvas with all the other elements (grid lines, scale labels...) hidden, style the line differently (thicker and in a gray shade). Then position this duplicate canvas under and to the bottom and right of the original canvas.

**CSS**

```
.shadowParent {
    position: relative;
}
.shadowParent canvas.firstShadow {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="shadowParent">
    <canvas id="myChartShadow" class="firstShadow" width="600"></canvas>
    <canvas id="myChart" width="600"></canvas>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
...

var ctxShadow = document.getElementById("myChartShadow").getContext("2d");
var dataShadow = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
dataShadow.datasets[0].strokeColor = "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)"
new Chart(ctxShadow).Line(dataShadow, {
    datasetStrokeWidth: 10,
    datasetFill: false,
    pointDot: false,
    showTooltips: false,
});
```

---

If your shadow isn't blurry enough you could add one more layer

**CSS**

```
.shadowParent canvas.secondShadow {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="shadowParent">
    <canvas id="myChartShadow2" class="secondShadow" width="600"></canvas>
    ...
```

**Script**

```
var ctxShadow2 = document.getElementById("myChartShadow2").getContext("2d");
var dataShadow2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
dataShadow2.datasets[0].strokeColor = "rgba(220,220,220,0.1)"
new Chart(ctxShadow2).Line(dataShadow2, {
    datasetStrokeWidth: 20,
    datasetFill: false,
    pointDot: false,
    showTooltips: false,
    scaleFontColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    scaleLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    scaleShowGridLines: false,
    datasetFill: false,
});
```

Note that the scale aligns with the first shadow (it gives it a more 3D feel), but you can move it to the first layer if the scale is important (vs. this being more of an rough look kind of graph)

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fjyj1021/

---

[image]

Comment: hmm, but then it'll be a solid colour wouldn't it? Rather than looking like a shadow?

Comment: You can set a transparency or gray shade (better) for the underlying line and make it thicker to give a shadow kind of look.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I get what you mean, but there'd be no blur, so i'm not sure how much of a shadow it would actually look

Comment: It looks pretty ok even without the blur (esp. given your dark background). But you can add more layers if you want the blur  (check out the picture). Though you'd probably want to refactor if you want more than 2 layers, or if there is more than one instance of the graph. Btw, you might also want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31896466 (seeing that you also have a color gradient)

Comment: Okay that's pretty impressive, and that link to your answer with gradients is awesome too. Thank you so much, this is going to help me loads :)

Comment: Btw, just realized you already have the color gradient code. I kind of missed that!! What you have is better. The one I linked to is unnecessarily complex if you don't want the points

Comment: Haha that's okay. I'm not using points at the moment but other graphs may so have noted the post for future reference. You've been a great help :)

Comment: Whoops! Even that was not required! I just tacked on a link to this question from my answer there. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Not at all :) I don't suppose you know how to round off the line at all? The beginning and end of the line just cuts off straight haha

Comment: Maybe setting the pointDot to true and messing around with the pointRadius and colors might help - check out http://jsfiddle.net/j8r4o1pc/ for a crude attempt

Answer (score 0):

You can use filters:

```
    g.ct-series {filter:url(#shadow);}
    <defs>
        <filter id="shadow" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feDropShadow dx="2" dy="2" stdDeviation="6" flood-opacity="0.80" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
```