# How do I add a shadow to a line in Chart.js v4?

Tags: chart.js

I am trying to upgrade an application that creates a graph using flot.js 0.8.3 to use Chart.js 4.4.0 instead.  By default, Flot.js created lines with a slight drop shadow underneath them, and I want to recreate that effect in Chart.js.

This appears to be staggeringly hard.  The question has been asked several places, typically without reference to the Chart.js version involved, but I can't find anything that seems to address anything greater than v2.

So far I've found four questions on Stack Overflow and two issues on the Chart.js GitHub that have enough information for me to attempt a solution.  None of them work, and it seems like changes in the Chart.js namespace between versions is at least a large part of the reason.

- [Source 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33104231/is-it-possible-to-add-a-drop-shadow-to-chart-js-line-chart) (2015-10-13) -- The two answers here suggest duplicating the entire canvas and manipulating it to create a second, "shadow" graph, and something involving CSS filters.  The first approach seems unreasonably difficult to implement as well as inefficient, and the second I don't understand well enough to try to implement.  Nothing about the answer gives me any confidence that taking days to research and attempt to implement it will be worthwhile.
- [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273254/styling-bars-and-lines-with-chart-js) (2015-12-14) -- This comes closest to being useful.

  - The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34311198/6673905) (2015-12-16) suggests extending `Chart.types.Line` to add a shadow effect.  When I try this using Chart.js 4.4.0, it throws the console error `Chart.types is undefined`, which seems to be the kind of version namespace error I mentioned.
  - The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43479325/6673905) (2017-04-18) is the rare answer that bothers to specify the version it applies to, Chart.js v2.  It suggests overriding the Chart.js `draw()` function `Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw` (or `Chart.controllers.scatter.prototype.draw` in my case).  When I try this using Chart.js 4.4.0, the plot appears with no shadow, and it throws the console error `this.chart.chart is undefined`.  I assume this is another namespace change between versions.
  - The [third answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54580284/6673905) (2019-02-07) suggests something called a Plugin.  As written, the suggested Plugin uses something called `pluginService` that for Chart.js 4.4.0 throws the console error `Chart.pluginService is undefined`.  However, I've found that more recent versions of Chart.js place the plugin reference as a property within the unnamed `{}` argument to `Chart()` as `plugins: simpleplugin` instead of using `pluginService`.  When I try the latter approach with Chart.js v4.4.0, it draws a plot as normal and throws no errors, but there is no shadow.
- [Source 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41426611/how-to-filter-shadow-or-drop-shadow-in-chart-js) (2017-01-02) -- This has only [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41429642/6673905), which is a large selection of several chunks of code presented without any explanation or even a quick description of the solution strategy being attempted.  It would take a week of study to parse it out line-by-line, abstract its important points, and attempt to apply these to my code.  I'm posting here in hopes of finding a more efficient path to a solution.
- [Source 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43439191/chartjs-v2-stroke-shadow) (2017-04-16) -- This question does specify Chart.js v2.  However, its [only answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43441848/6673905) is identical to the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43479325/6673905) of Source 2, which I've already tried unsuccessfully.
- [Source 5](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/1786) (2015-12-15) is a Chart.js GitHub issue that is essentially identical to [Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273254/styling-bars-and-lines-with-chart-js) from Stack Overflow, and presumably posted by the same person.  Its thread has virtually no actionable information compared to the Stack Overflow post, however.
- [Source 6](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4977) is another Chart.js GitHub issue.  Its thread recommends extending the Line element using `Chart.elements.Line.extend(...)` to add a shadow effect.  When I try this using Chart.js 4.4.0, it throws the console error `Chart.elements.Line is undefined`, which again seems to be a version namespace error.

I've found a handful of other questions on this site and on other forums that touch on the problem of Chart.js drop shadows, but all seem to duplicate what I've already tried and documented above.

Is there a commonly accepted, reasonably easy to understand and implement approach to creating a Flot.js-style drop shadow in Chart.js v4?

**Update:**  A commenter and I have established that the Plugin approach ([Source 2, Answer 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54580284/6673905)) does create a shadow under the graph line, but it also creates shadows under everything else.  The result I and presumably everyone else who visits this question are interested in is one where the shadow is under the graph line only.

Comment: Using the [third answer of the 2nd source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54580284/6673905), I've managed to do [this](https://codepen.io/Frixionder/pen/wvRZPKx). While I don't think it completely answers your question, I hope it'll help you.

Comment: @Frixionder I had come up with something similar myself.  Unfortunately, that approach adds shadows under everything -- grid lines, borders, etc. -- not just the graph line.  I'll add it as a note to the current question, but it's probably a whole separate question to fix.