# Is there a way to add a drop shadow for one specific line in the line chart containing many lines?

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I am trying to add a drop shadow for one specific line in the chart.

This helped somehow but was not enough:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33124653/4500286

I am using the package of `"react-chartjs-2": "2.7.6"` in a react project.
What I came up with, adds a drop shadow for all the lines .. I can't seem to find a way to add it per dataset.

I have prepended this code to the `componentWillMount` that adds a drop shadow to all the lines (which isn't what I want)

```
    Chart.pluginService.register({
      id: 'dropShadow',
      afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
        console.log(chart);
        let originial = this;
        const { ctx } = chart;
        let originalStroke = ctx.stroke;
        ctx.stroke = function () {
          ctx.save();
          ctx.shadowColor = '#C4A4BF';
          ctx.shadowBlur = 7;
          ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
          ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
          originalStroke.apply(this, arguments)
          ctx.restore();
        }
      }
    });
```

This is a mini sample of the code I'm tried to build

```
import React from 'react';
import mediaPlanner from '../api/mediaPlanner';
import {Line,Chart} from "react-chartjs-2";


class Revenue extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: {}
    }

    this.graphDataSample = {
      forecastRevenue: ["3000", "3500", "3500"]
      revenue: ["1000", "3000", "5000"]
      timestamp: ["2019-02-01", "2019-02-02", "2019-02-03"] 
    }
    // get up the options of the graph
    this.options = {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: 'bottom',
        labels: {
          fontColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
        }
      },
      tooltips: {
        backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5",
        titleFontColor: "#333",
        bodyFontColor: "#666",
        bodySpacing: 4,
        xPadding: 12,
        mode: "nearest",
        intersect: 0,
        position: "nearest"
      },
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        yAxes: [
          {
            barPercentage: 1.6,
            gridLines: {
              drawBorder: false,
              color: "rgba(29,140,248,0.0)",
              zeroLineColor: "transparent"
            },
            ticks: {
              suggestedMin: 60,
              suggestedMax: 125,
              padding: 20,
              fontColor: "#9a9a9a"
            }
          }
        ],
        xAxes: [
          {
            barPercentage: 1.6,
            gridLines: {
              drawBorder: false,
              color: "rgba(29,140,248,0.1)",
              zeroLineColor: "transparent"
            },
            ticks: {
              padding: 20,
              fontColor: "#9a9a9a"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    };
  }

  componentWillMount = () => {
      // supposed to make an api call to get the data returned
      // by graphDataSample

    // adds the drop shadow to both revenue and forecast revenue
    // I only want to add it to the forecast revenue

    Chart.pluginService.register({
      id: 'dropShadow',
      afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
        console.log(chart);
        let originial = this;
        const { ctx } = chart;
        let originalStroke = ctx.stroke;
        ctx.stroke = function () {
          ctx.save();
          ctx.shadowColor = '#C4A4BF';
          ctx.shadowBlur = 7;
          ctx.shadowOffsetX = 0;
          ctx.shadowOffsetY = 0;
          originalStroke.apply(this, arguments)
          ctx.restore();
        }
      }
    });

    this.setState({data: function(canvas){
      return {
        labels: this.graphDataSample.timestamp, // X-axis
        datasets: [
          {
            fill: false,
            borderColor: "#6C6C74",
            borderWidth: 3,
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            pointBackgroundColor: "#6C6C74",
            pointHoverRadius: 0,
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 10,
            pointBorderWidth: 0,
            steppedLine: false,
            pointRadius: 0,
            label: "Revenue ($)",
            data: this.graphDataSample.revenue, // Y-axis
          },
          {
            fill: false,
            borderColor: "red",
            borderWidth: 3,
            borderDash: [],
            borderDashOffset: 0.0,
            pointBackgroundColor: "red",
            pointHoverRadius: 0,
            pointHoverBorderWidth: 10,
            pointBorderWidth: 0,
            steppedLine: false,
            pointRadius: 0,
            label: "Forecast Revenue ($)",
            data: this.graphDataSample.forecastRevenue, // Y-axis
          }
        ]
      };
    }});
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Line
          data={this.state.data}
          options={this.options}
        />
    );
  }
}
export default Revenue;
```

As said the expected is to add a drop shadow to one line in my case is for the forecast revenue and not the revenue
That's a screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LjLyXEPGlgqlE1AziUQdf0GZJptwVEyf/view?usp=sharing